# tree from array of dot-separated strings

Tags: javascript, tree, leaflet

I have an array of dot delimited strings which looks like the following

```
data = [
    'Europe.UK.London.TrafalgarSq', 
    'Europe.UK.London.HydePark', 
    'Europe.UK.London.OxfordStreet', 
    'Europe.UK.London.City.Bank', 
    'Europe.France.Paris', 
    'Europe.France.Bordeaux'},
]
```

and I want to build the following tree of of nested objects. In case it matters, this is for a `leaflet` map where the [Tree Layers Control](https://github.com/jjimenezshaw/Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree) is going to be used

```
var tree = {
    label: 'Places',
    selectAllCheckbox: 'Un/select all',
    children: [
        {
            label: 'Europe',
            selectAllCheckbox: true,
            children: [
                {
                    label: 'Europe.UK',
                    selectAllCheckbox: true,
                    children: [
                        {
                            label: 'Europe.UK.London',
                            selectAllCheckbox: true,
                            children: [
                                {label: 'Europe.UK.London.TrafalgarSq'},
                                {label: 'Europe.UK.London.HydePark'},
                                {label: 'Europe.UK.London.OxfordStreet'},
                                {
                                    label: 'Europe.UK.London.City',
                                    selectAllCheckbox: true,
                                    children: [
                                        {label: 'Europe.UK.London.City.Bank'},
                                    ]
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Europe.France',
                            selectAllCheckbox: true,
                            children: [
                                {label: 'Europe.France.Paris'},
                                {label: 'Europe.France.Bordeaux'},
                            ]
                        },
                    ]

                }
            ]

        }
    ]
};
```

How do I do this tree please?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `mapper` object which has partial paths (or `label`) as key and a reference to the object in the tree as it's value. `split` the path at `.` and `reduce` the array with `tree` as the `initialValue`. If the `path` doesn't exist yet, add it to mapper and tree. Return the nested object in each iteration.

```js
const data = ["Europe.UK.London.TrafalgarSq","Europe.UK.London.HydePark","Europe.UK.London.OxfordStreet","Europe.UK.London.City.Bank","Europe.France.Paris","Europe.France.Bordeaux"],
    mapper = {},
    tree = {
      label: 'Places',
      selectAllCheckbox: 'Un/select all',
      children: []
    }

for (const str of data) {
  let splits = str.split('.'),
      label = '';

  splits.reduce((parent, place) => {
    if (label)
      label += `.${place}`
    else
      label = place

    if (!mapper[label]) {
      const o = { label };
      mapper[label] = o;
      parent.selectAllCheckbox = true
      parent.children = parent.children || [];
      parent.children.push(o)
    }

    return mapper[label];
  }, tree)
}

console.log(tree)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I spent most of the Saturday trying to do it and I got nothing at all. I am now trying to understand your solution. Can you please explain a bit more `mapper`, `parent` and the return value from the reducer? `parent` at the next iteration should take the return value of the reducer ( which is `mapper[label]`) but how  the `tree` gets gradually built up please? Also those 3 lines inside the if statement in the reducer where you set the key/value pairs of the `parent` object can you expand a bit please. How is this related to the `tree` object please? Thx again!

Answer (score 4):

You could an iterative approach with a reduceing of the nested objects.

```js
var data = ['Europe.UK.London.TrafalgarSq', 'Europe.UK.London.HydePark', 'Europe.UK.London.OxfordStreet', 'Europe.UK.London.City.Bank', 'Europe.France.Paris', 'Europe.France.Bordeaux'],
    children = data.reduce((r, s) => {
        s.split('.').reduce((q, _, i, a) => {
            q.selectAllCheckbox = true;
            var label = a.slice(0, i + 1).join('.'),
                temp = (q.children = q.children || []).find(o => o.label === label);
            if (!temp) q.children.push(temp = { label });
            return temp;
        }, r);
        return r;
    }, { children: [] }).children,
    tree = { label: 'Places', selectAllCheckbox: 'Un/select all', children };

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina for your help! I am really poor with the reduce function but I try to understand it. In its basic form, like multiplication/addition I am ok but I really struggle with more demanding cases. The main reason I accepted `adiga`s answer is because it looks a bit simpler for my understanding.