# Nested array based on splitted string

Tags: javascript

I have string like that:

```
const test = '1.1.1.2';
```

from this string I need create nested array:

```
{
  items :[{
    name: '1',
    items: [{
      name:'1.1',
      items:[{
        name: '1.1.1',
        items: [{
          name: '1.1.1.2'
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

how can I that? thanks for any help

This is the attempted code

```js
function foo(test, items2, item, index) {
  if (test.hasOwnProperty('items') && test.items instanceof Array && test.items.length === 0) {
    var varoo = test.items.push({
      name: items2[index],
      items: []
    });
    foo(varoo, items2, item, index)
  } else {
    test = {
      name: items2[index],
      items: []
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Similar question: [tree from array of dot-separated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490323)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below I guess

```js
function createElement(parent, childs){
    if ( childs && childs.length > 0){
      return {
          items: [
              {
                name: parent,
                items: createElement(parent + '.' + childs[0],childs.slice(1))
              }
          ]

      }
    }
    return  {
          items: [
              {
                name: parent,
                items: []
              }
          ]

      }
}

const items = "1.2.3.4".split(".");
const element = createElement(items[0],items.slice(1));
console.log(element);
```