# Javascript workaround to nest an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I get some data in a flat array and I want to nest one inside another.
The attribute which defines the depth of an object is the `DEPENDENCY` where I split it in so as to get the different levels of nesting.

This is the data I get

```
const initArray = [
  { NAME: "initArray", DEPENDENCY: "0", VAR1: "VAR1", VAR2: "VAR2" },
  { NAME: "initArray2", DEPENDENCY: "0.0", VAR1: "VAR1", VAR2: "VAR2" },
  { NAME: "initArray3", DEPENDENCY: "0.1", VAR1: "VAR1", VAR2: "VAR2" },
  { NAME: "initArray4", DEPENDENCY: "0.0.0", VAR1: "VAR1", VAR2: "VAR2" },
  { NAME: "initArray5", DEPENDENCY: "0.0.1", VAR1: "VAR1", VAR2: "VAR2" },
  { NAME: "initArray6", DEPENDENCY: "0.0.2", VAR1: "VAR1", VAR2: "VAR2" },
  { NAME: "initArray7", DEPENDENCY: "0.1.1", VAR1: "VAR1", VAR2: "VAR2" },
  { NAME: "initArray8", DEPENDENCY: "0.1.2", VAR1: "VAR1", VAR2: "VAR2" },
  { NAME: "initArray9", DEPENDENCY: "0.1.3", VAR1: "VAR1", VAR2: "VAR2" },
  { NAME: "initArray10", DEPENDENCY: "0.1.4", VAR1: "VAR1", VAR2: "VAR2" },
  { NAME: "initArray11", DEPENDENCY: "0.1.5", VAR1: "VAR1", VAR2: "VAR2" },
];
```

and this the expected result

```
const myArray = [
  {
    NAME: "initArray",
    DEPENDENCY: "0",
    VAR1: "VAR1",
    VAR2: "VAR2",
    CHILDREN: [
      {
        NAME: "initArray2",
        DEPENDENCY: "0.0",
        VAR1: "VAR1",
        VAR2: "VAR2",
        CHILDREN: [
          {
            NAME: "initArray4",
            DEPENDENCY: "0.0.0",
            VAR1: "VAR1",
            VAR2: "VAR2",
          },
          {
            NAME: "initArray5",
            DEPENDENCY: "0.0.1",
            VAR1: "VAR1",
            VAR2: "VAR2",
          },
          {
            NAME: "initArray6",
            DEPENDENCY: "0.0.2",
            VAR1: "VAR1",
            VAR2: "VAR2",
         },
       ],
     },
     {
       NAME: "initArray3",
       DEPENDENCY: "0.1",
       VAR1: "VAR1",
       VAR2: "VAR2",
       CHILDREN: [
         {
           NAME: "initArray7",
           DEPENDENCY: "0.1.1",
           VAR1: "VAR1",
           VAR2: "VAR2",
         },
         {
           NAME: "initArray8",
           DEPENDENCY: "0.1.2",
           VAR1: "VAR1",
           VAR2: "VAR2",
         },
         {
           NAME: "initArray9",
           DEPENDENCY: "0.1.3",
           VAR1: "VAR1",
           VAR2: "VAR2",
         },
         {
           NAME: "initArray10",
           DEPENDENCY: "0.1.4",
           VAR1: "VAR1",
           VAR2: "VAR2",
         },
         {
           NAME: "initArray11",
           DEPENDENCY: "0.1.5",
           VAR1: "VAR1",
           VAR2: "VAR2",
         },
       ],
     },
   ],
  },
];
```

This can be done by the following code

```
let myArray = Array();

Object.keys(initArray).map((key) => {
  const dependencyTree = initArray[key].DEPENDENCY.split(".");

  if (dependencyTree.length === 1) {
    myArray[Number(dependencyTree[0])] = initArray[key];
  } else if (dependencyTree.length === 2) {
    if (!myArray[Number(dependencyTree[0])].hasOwnProperty("CHILDREN")) {
      myArray[Number(dependencyTree[0])].CHILDREN = Array();
    }

    myArray[Number(dependencyTree[0])].CHILDREN[Number(dependencyTree[1])] = initArray[key];
  } else if (dependencyTree.length === 3) {
    if (!myArray[Number(dependencyTree[0])].CHILDREN[Number(dependencyTree[1])].hasOwnProperty("CHILDREN")) {
      myArray[Number(dependencyTree[0])].CHILDREN[Number(dependencyTree[1])].CHILDREN = Array();
    }

    myArray[Number(dependencyTree[0])].CHILDREN[Number(dependencyTree[1])].CHILDREN.push(initArray[key]);
  }
});
```

but I would like a solution for nesting regardless the depth. Now I have to add manually the if statement for each depth level. Is there any workaround?

Comment: My answer on a similar question: [tree from array of dot-separated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490323)

Comment: Your solution works, but it just adds a nested label. I need to add nested objects.

Comment: You just need to tweak a little. Instead of splitting the string, you need to split the property: `for (const obj of data) { let splits = obj.DEPENDENCY.split('.')` And instead of `const o = { label }`, you need `const o = { ...obj }`

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/7etafd25/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesting a flat list with arbitrary depth has common recursive algorithm.

The code below is a working example with your dataset.

Another thing to keep in mind is that this code does NOT mutate your original flat list

```
 function generateNesting(originalList, nestedList) {
      return nestedList.map((item) => {
        const { DEPENDENCY: parentDependency } = item;
        const childItems = originalList.filter((item) => item.DEPENDENCY.startsWith(parentDependency) && item.DEPENDENCY.length - 2 === parentDependency.length);
    
    return { ...item, CHILDREN: generateNesting(originalList, childItems) };
  });
}

function makeNested(list) {
  const rootItems = list.filter((item) =>
    item.DEPENDENCY.length === 1
  );

  return generateNesting(list, rootItems);
}

function searchByName(name, nestedList = []) {
    for(let i = 0; i < nestedList.length; i++) {
        const { NAME, CHILDREN } = nestedList[i]

        if(NAME === name) {
            return nestedList[i]
        }

        const found = searchByName(name, CHILDREN)

        if(found) {
            return found
        }
    }
}

const result = makeNested(initArray) // initArray is your flat list
console.log(searchByName('initArray3', result))
console.log(searchByName('initArray10', result))
console.log(searchByName('initArrayISNOTPRESENT', result)) // prints undefined
```

Comment: Ok now one more thing. How do I search for a name on the nested array and extract it to a single object? For example, let's say I search for the object with NAME = initArray4. Which is inside initArray2 object, which is inside initArray object. How to filter the whole nested array and keep only the initArray4 object?

Comment: @iNemesis 
I added the searchByName function.
Searching (and/or traversing) is core to a nested/tree-like data structure.

I suggest you read about tree/nested data structures and related algorithms

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies. I definitely will read about tree/nested data structures for better understanding your code. Once again, i really appreciate your time