# How to parse an objects with array index to object array with key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arraylist, javascript-objects

Convert this object Students object to one Students array

```
{"SubmitBy":"SK", "Students[0].name":"Jhon", "Students[0].age":"15", "Students[1].name":"Sam", "Students[1].age":"16", "Students[2].name":"Tom", "Students[2].age":15}
```

Result expecting like this

```
{SubmitBy:"SK", Students:[{name:"Jhon", age:"15"},{name:"Sam", age:"16"},{name:"Tom", age:"15"} ]}
```

Comment: duplicate: [Javascript: Convert dot-delimited strings to nested object value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058519/javascript-convert-dot-delimited-strings-to-nested-object-value)

Comment: or [tree from array of dot-separated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490323/tree-from-array-of-dot-separated-strings)

Answer (score 1):

You can use library like [`dot-prop`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dot-prop) to achieve this, code below:

```js
import { setProperty } from 'dot-prop';

const input = {
  SubmitBy: 'SK',
  'Students[0].name': 'Jhon',
  'Students[0].age': '15',
  'Students[1].name': 'Sam',
  'Students[1].age': '16',
  'Students[2].name': 'Tom',
  'Students[2].age': 15
};
const output = {};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(input)) {
  setProperty(output, key, value);
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const originalData = {"SubmitBy":"SK", "Students[0].name":"Jhon", "Students[0].age":"15", "Students[1].name":"Sam", "Students[1].age":"16", "Students[2].name":"Tom", "Students[2].age":15};

const transformedData = { SubmitBy: originalData.SubmitBy, Students: [] };

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const student = {
    name: originalData[`Students[${i}].name`],
    age: originalData[`Students[${i}].age`].toString(),
  };
  transformedData.Students.push(student);
}

console.log(transformedData);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).